# Often I do an Image Trace of a hand-drawn work or .psd but can't seem to select Simplify?? Why?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I just want to reduce shake and pixelation. I have memories of doing this in previous versions to tidy up work. Does anyone know why the option is greyed out and not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **Expand** the trace first by clicking the <kbd>Expand</kbd> button on the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.